# Problem coming with find function of python

Tags: python, string

I am working on a string manipulation related task, where I have a search a string which contains some data along with different Table numbers like Table 1, Table 2,.. etc and attach the table data on finding the match. **For Example, the String of data can be :  The information related to requirement 1 is present in Table 1, Table 2 and Table 12.** For doing with, I made a small code with find function in python.

```
totalStrings=20
# listToStringData is a String which contains a large number of strings with Table 1, Table 2 etc mentioned in their text 
# dictTablesData   is Dictionary which contains all the Tables Data
z=0
while(z < totalStrings):
    serial=1
    data = ""
    while serial<= totalNumberOfTables:
        if(listToStringData[z].find("Table "+str(serial))!=-1):
            data = data+ dictTablesData["Table " + str(serial)]                
            
        serial=serial+1
    z=z+1
```

For all the Table numbers below 10, my code works perfectly.
The problem in my code is that if the string I am searching contains a word say 'Table 12', I end up attaching Table 1 and Table 12 data both. Please suggest me some way to overcome this problem.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: If you still need help after debugging, please [edit] your question to show a [mcve]. Your current code has many variables that are not defined.

Comment: Thank you @Code-Apprentice. I will edit the question to make more clear.

Comment: Do you mean that `listToStringData` is a **list** of strings rather than a "string which contains a large number of strings"? Can you provide some example data for both `listToStringData` and `dictTablesData`?

Comment: What happens when one of the strings is like `'This is not Table 1, it is Table 2'`?

Comment: I really apologize @Code-Apprentice for not clarifying the problem well. I have clarified the problem.

Comment: I some how managed to solve the problem. I will share my answer.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain what the problem is. It seems that your claim "For all the Table numbers below 10, my code works perfectly" is not correct. From what I can tell, these tables below 10 can all cause problems. I strongly suggest you read the link in my first comment for tips about how to find the problem.

Comment: Thank @Code-Apprentice. Your all the links helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here can be illustrated with a simple example:

```
String s = "Requirement 1 is present in Table 12";
int i = s.find("Table 1");
```

This will find a match. You need to find a way to avoid this. One possible solution is to use regular expressions to parse the word "Table" and the number. Then you can compare with strict equality if any of those are the table you are looking for.

Comment: I think the `r'(Table /d+)'`s are surrounded by other stuff.  You can use a regexp (like the one shown) to extract a full table name.  Make sure to check that there is a match though.

Comment: @pat Good point. The OP is unclear about the format of the strings in `listToStringData`. My speculation here shows a solution to the simplest possible format. We should wait for more info from the OP before speculating further. In fact I'm probably speculating too much just with this answer.

Comment: Thank you @Code-Apprentice. I agree that something like a Regex would be most stable  Solution for this kind of problem.